# Hokuyo laser not publishing any data

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, hokuyo, jackal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Jackal with a Hokuyo laser and I am wanting the hokuyo laser to publish information to /front/scan so that I am able to use the Nav stack with my jackal robot, but I am unsure how to do this. The hokuyo is properly connected to the jackal but is not publishing any data for some reason.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297137/hokuyo-laser-not-publishing-any-data/) by [dkrivet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36368/dkrivet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2018-07-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-07-12**:
Which hokuyo LiDAR are you using? It is connected via USB or ethernet? What node are you running to connect with the LiDAR?

**Comment by [dkrivet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36368/dkrivet/) on 2018-07-12**:
I am using the Hokuyo UTM-30LX connected via USB. I am unsure of what node to use to connect to the LiDAR, that is the issue. Any help would be much appreciated, I am very new to ROS.

**Comment by [dkrivet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36368/dkrivet/) on 2018-07-12**:
Ideally I want to publish the LiDAR data to a topic named /front/scan so I can use the nav stack to do autonomous navigation with the jackal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to install and run the [URG node](http://wiki.ros.org/urg_node) (URG is the protocol the hokuyo sensors use) which will connect to the hardware and publish the laser scan messages to the ROS system. You should be able to install this easily using apt-get.

By default this node publishes laser scan messages on the `/scan` topic, you can change this using a [remap](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap) in your launch file to any topic name you want.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dkrivet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36368/dkrivet/) on 2018-07-13**:
Thank you for the help. I have done this and got the laser to publish data correctly, however it is not publishing to my desired frame. I have actually used the hokuyo_node as the jackal is running ROS indigo and I think the hokuyo_node adds messages to the "laser" frame by default

**Comment by [dkrivet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36368/dkrivet/) on 2018-07-13**:
However, I want to publish the the "front_laser" frame. How would I go about doing this? Thank you very much

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-07-13**:
You can use the parameter `frame_id` to set the frame laser scans are published in. The documentation isn't that clear on this unfortunately.